# Convert a single-column pyodbc row into a plain integer value

Tags: python, pyodbc

I am passing data to a sql statement in python, the code part is like this:

```
    foo.execute("select test_dat_id from tbl_dat_test where sample_id =?",(n_value,))
    myfoo = foo.fetchall() 
    zoo = "select result_value from tbl_dat_analyte where test_dat_id ="
    for new in myfoo:
     new1=str(new)
     new2=float(new1)
     var = zoo + new2
     print(var)
    foo.execute(var)
```

To make the long story short, myfoo is sql row, and i converted its entries to string, this is a number mainly with a space and brackets, (Like this: (964005, ))
simply i want it to be converted to integer so it can pass to the sql statment, i believe there is easier ways to do so, but i really can't get it, thanks.

Comment: You should **always** pass SQL variables into a statement as arguments. Not only does it solve this problem but it makes you less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Please provide a working code exemple to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way would be to use regular expressions:

```
import re
foo = "(100)   "
foo = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", foo)
foo = int(foo)
```

This will remove all non-numeric characters, and convert the string to int.

Comment: Thanks, actually i did a very similar thing:

new2=str(new)
 new2=new2.replace(" ", "")
 new2=new2.replace("(", "")
 new2=new2.replace(",)", "")

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your need correctly here's what you need to do

```py
string_with_number_and_whitespaces = '(100)  ' # Also contains brackets 
string_with_number_only = string_with_number_and_whitespaces.replace(' ', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
number = int(string_with_number_only)
print(number) # Output 100
```

Answer (score 0):

`.fetchall()` returns a list of  `pyodbc.Row` objects. If you want the first (and only) element in the row just extract it using index `[0]`

```
>>> myfoo = [(1,),(2,)]
>>> for new in myfoo:
...     myint = new[0]
...     print(myint * 10)
...
10
20
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for all your valuable answers, i am going to give them a try one by one, actually before i get your feed back, i  got it working like this (I know its a primitive solution but its worked):

```
  foo.execute("select test_dat_id from tbl_dat_test where sample_id =?",(n_value,))
myfoo = foo.fetchall()
myfoo2 = dict(enumerate(item[0:100] for item in myfoo))
v_value = list(myfoo2.values())[0:100]
zoo = "select result_value from tbl_dat_analyte where test_dat_id = "
for new in v_value:
 new2=str(new)
 new2=new2.replace(" ", "")
 new2=new2.replace("(", "")
 new2=new2.replace(",)", "")
 var = zoo + new2
 print(var)
 foo100 = cnx.cursor()
 foo100.execute(var)
 myzoo = foo100.fetchall()
 print('zoo is:')
 print(myzoo)
 c5a = my_sheet.cell(row= 21 , column = 3)
 c5a.value = myzoo
```